# SQL How to pivot and aggregate another column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm trying to pivot a table but also group each record into one. This is my problem:

I have a table which has the [SchemeCode], [MonthYear] and [Revenue]. Each [SchemeCode] has multiple [MonthYear] and its corresponding [Revenue].

```
| Scheme Code | MonthYear | Revenue |
|-------------|-----------|---------|
| 18VDA       | 2018.1    | 100     |
| 18VDA       | 2018.2    | 200     |
| 18VDA       | 2018.3    | 200     |
```

But I'm trying to make it so it comes out like this:

```
| Scheme Code | 2018.1 | 2018.2 | 2018.3 |
|-------------|--------|--------|--------|
| 18VDA       | 100    | 200    | 300    |
```

I know how normal pivoting works, but the problem is that when I do, the output keeps the three 18VDA records like this:

```
| Scheme Code | 2018.1 | 2018.2 | 2018.3 |
|-------------|--------|--------|--------|
| 18VDA       | 100    | --     | --     |
| 18VDA       | --     | 200    | --     |
| 18VDA       | --     | --     | 300    |
```

I want the scheme codes to all aggregate into one as well. Below is the code I used to create the table above:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([MonthYear]) 
                    from TableA
                    group by [MonthYear]--, id
                    --order by id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = '[Scheme Code],' + @cols + '

from TableA
pivot(sum([Revenue]) for MonthYear in (' + @cols + ') 

          ) as RevenueMonth'

          execute(@query);
```

Can someone help me on how I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This below code-

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@sqlCommand  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @cols =
STUFF((SELECT   ( '],[' +  A.MonthYear)
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MonthYear FROM TableA) A
        ORDER BY A.MonthYear 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1,1,'')+']'
FROM TableA

--SELECT @cols

SET @sqlCommand= 
N'SELECT [Scheme Code],'+SUBSTRING(@cols,2,LEN(@cols))+'
FROM 
(
    SELECT [Scheme Code],[MonthYear],[Revenue] FROM your_table
) AS P
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Revenue)
    FOR MonthYear IN('+SUBSTRING(@cols,2,LEN(@cols))+')
) PVT'

--PRINT @sqlCommand
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and worked for me. Had to used temp table, but that doesn't makes any difference. At first did generate an error, but by adding the **select** keyword to the *@query* it did provide the desired result.

```
| Scheme Code   | 2018.1 | 2018.2   | 2018.3    |
|---------------|--------|----------|-----------| 
| 18VDA         | 100    | 200      | 200       |
```

The test query:

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#TableA') is not null drop table #TableA
create table #TableA ([Scheme Code] varchar(20), [MonthYear] varchar(20), [Revenue] int)

insert into #TableA( [Scheme Code], MonthYear, Revenue )
values
    ('18VDA','2018.1',100)
    , ('18VDA','2018.2',200)
    , ('18VDA', '2018.3',200)


declare @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([MonthYear]) 
                    from #TableA
                    group by [MonthYear]--, id
                    --order by id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'select [Scheme Code],' + @cols + '

from #TableA
pivot(sum([Revenue]) for MonthYear in (' + @cols + ') 

          ) as RevenueMonth'


print @query
          execute(@query)
```

What MSSQL are you using?